# How to receive a dynamic response in a Swagger spec

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I want to request a table from my database through my API. However, I don't know what number of columns the table will have, or what it will contain. How can I specify this in Swagger? This is what I would like to do:

```
paths:
  /reports/{id}:
    get:
      summary: Detailed results
      description: filler
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: filler
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: array
            items: 
              $ref: '#/definitions/DynamicObject'
definitions:
  DynamicObject:
    type: object
    properties:
      **$IDONTKNOWWHATTODO**
```

Any ideas on how to define a JSON object with no specific parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To describe arbitrary JSON, please use `"type": "object"`. Here is an example in JSON:

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "successful operation",
        "schema": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    },
```