# How to define schema arbitrary JSON object?

Tags: json, swagger, jsonschema, openapi, oas

I am trying to define a API using OAS v2 that will return a payload along with some metadata.

In other words, the response to the API will be:

```
{
  "metadata":[
   {
     "key" :"key1",
     "value": "value1"
   }
  ],
  "payload": {Valid JSON}
}
```

The payload can be anything, and different for different scenarios, the only constraint being it will be a valid JSON format. So, at this point in time, I would like to define it just as a JSON object without defining the field level details.

How can I do that in OAS2/JSON schema?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger 2.0: what schema to accept any (complex) JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841298/swagger-2-0-what-schema-to-accept-any-complex-json-value), [Freeform subobject in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41606152/113116) and [How to receive a dynamic response in a Swagger spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35782175/113116).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use an empty schema (`{}`) for payload.

JSON Schema relies on valid JSON value and you won't be able to supply it if your response is a malformed JSON.

If payload value is malformed, whole response will not be a valid JSON.

In other words, this issue is out of JSON Schema scope, but rather in scope of your response decoder (that should fail on malformed response body).